# How to avoid extra memory use during encryption and decryption?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

So I have a basic crypto class. Note that this is a simplified implementation to illustrate the question.

Now to my mind both these methods have an extra byte array and string instance.

`xmlString` and `bytes` in `Encrypt`

and

`decryptedString` and `decryptedBytes` in `Decrypt`

So how can I rework the usage of streams in this class to minimize the memory usage?

```
class Crypto 
{
    Rijndael rijndael;

    public Crypto()
    {
        rijndael = Rijndael.Create();
        rijndael.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"); ;
        rijndael.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"); ;
        rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(object obj)
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                OmitXmlDeclaration = true
            };

        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
            xmlWriter.Flush();
        }

        var xmlString = sb.ToString();
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);
        using (var encryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor())
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            crypto.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            crypto.FlushFinalBlock();
            stream.Position = 0;
            var encrypted = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
            return encrypted;
        }
    }

    public T Decrypt<T>(byte[] encryptedValue)
    {
        byte[] decryptedBytes;
        using (var decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor())
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            crypto.Write(encryptedValue, 0, encryptedValue.Length);
            crypto.FlushFinalBlock();
            stream.Position = 0;
            decryptedBytes = new Byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
        }

        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        var decryptedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(decryptedString))
        using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
        {
            return (T)ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);

        }
    }

}
```

And here is a unit test

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Run()
    {
        var before = new MyClassForSerialize()
            {
                Property = "Sdf"
            };

        var dataEncryptor = new Crypto();
        var encrypted = dataEncryptor.Encrypt(before);
        var after = dataEncryptor.Decrypt<MyClassForSerialize>(encrypted);
        Assert.AreEqual(before.Property, after.Property);
    }
}
public class MyClassForSerialize
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

=== Edit ===

Based on the anser from Damien_The_Unbeliever I tried this. Which fails the unit test

```
public byte[] Encrypt(object obj)
{
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        OmitXmlDeclaration = true
    };

    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

    using (var encryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor())
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(crypto, settings))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
            xmlWriter.Flush();
        }
        crypto.FlushFinalBlock();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `Stream`. IOW, serializing xml to a `Stream` will already be in a 'byte' form.

Comment: @leppie I know how it should work :) but i am running on lack of sleep and something about the interaction is alluding me

Comment: @leppie you are indeed correct. see full solution in answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct your `XmlWriter` directly on top of your `CryptoStream` (pass `crypto` to `XmlWriter.Create`), rather than using a separate buffer. (Ditto for decryption)

And `MemoryStream` has a `ToArray` method so you don't have to manually allocate, re-position and read from it.

Other than that, it looks like a reasonable implementation - are there specific issues that need fixing?

---

Based on your edit, if I change decrypt to:

```
    public T Decrypt<T>(byte[] encryptedValue)
    {
        using (var decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor())
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(encryptedValue))
            using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(crypto))
            {
                var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);

            }
    }
```

Then it seems to work for me.

---

The new version is including an XML BOM, whereas the old one wasn't. The XmlReader *should* cope, I'd have thought, but appears not to. Try the following settings in `Encrypt`:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false)
};
```

And now it works with the old `Decrypt` function.

### Full Solution

Encrypt

```
public byte[] Encrypt(object obj)
{
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
            Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false)
        };

    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");

    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
    using (var encryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor())
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(crypto, settings))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
            xmlWriter.Flush();
        }
        crypto.FlushFinalBlock();
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Decrypt

```
public T Decrypt<T>(byte[] encryptedValue)
{
    using (var decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor())
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(encryptedValue))
    using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)ser.Deserialize(crypto);
    }
}
```

Comment: but for the implementation to stay the same the encypted bytes must be the same. why is it different?

Comment: so basically there is already information encrypted with this algorithm. so the implementation has to remain the same

Comment: @Simon - see second update. Seems that including a BOM in the XML upsets the decryption routine.

Comment: are you on twitter? I am @simoncropp