# Deserialize appsettings.json with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core

I am doing encryption/decryption of my appsettings.json file within my ASP.NET application.

After decryption, my file is correctly decrypted to the following string:

﻿

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "IdentityServer4": "server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;database=IdentityServer4.Quickstart.EntityFramework;trusted_connection=yes"
  }
}
```

I would now like to convert that result to an object, which I attempt to do using the following line of code:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

When that line executes, I receive the following error:

```
"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: ﻿. Path '', line 0, position 0."
```

Comment: Have you logged the jsonString variable to verify that it contains valid JSON?

Comment: Possibly there's a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the string.  If so, see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1317700/3744182) for suggestions on how to resolve.

Comment: @dbc, you are absolutely correct.  Doing a `jsonString = jsonString.Trim(new char[] { '\uFEFF', '\u200B' });` resolved this.  Please submit an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the string.

To strip the BOM, see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1317700/3744182).

However, it would be better not to include it in the string to begin with.  If you have a byte array that includes a BOM and do:

```
var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
```

Then the BOM will be included.  But if you read the binary data with a `StreamReader` then the BOM will be processed and removed:

```
var jsonString = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(byteArray)).ReadToEnd();
```

(You could add `using` statements to that if you prefer, although `MemoryStream` doesn't actually need to be disposed.)

Or, stream, decrypt and deserialize all at once along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13947891/3744182) (for XML) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32944462/3744182) (for simultaneous decompression and deserialization of JSON).